# Options to CGBitmapContext for Drawining

Tags: xamarin.ios, quartz-graphics, cgbitmapcontext

Is there an option to the CGBitmapContext or Quartz 2D?
I want to use it for drawing on an UIImage in monotouch.

thanks Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing is always performed on a `CGContext`. If you want to draw onto an existing image, `CGBitmapContext` is logically the context to use.